# Getting config from newly installed ad lds

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

I just installed ad lds on my dev machine and am quite sure of what I specified as dn. I've never used ad lds before.

However, I cannot connect to it used ADSI Edit.

> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

`dsdbutil "list instances" quit` lists my instance with the colorful name "instance1".

If I force localhost (`LDAP://localhost:389/cn=dev,dn=xxx,dn=xx`) I instead get the error:

> No superior reference has been configured for the directory service. The directory service is therefore unable to issue referrals to objects outside this forest.

Is there a way to find out which dn I specified? or in any other way to connect to my instance?

Comment: The DN should be `cn=dev,dc=xxx,dc=xxx`

Comment: Doh. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In Adsiedit Connection Settings, under Connection Point, select "Configuration" well-known naming context from the drop down, with the Computer as "localhost:389"

Read the CN=Partitions folder for the "directory partition name" that you made - maybe you made a typo? Copy that, use it in a new connection in ADSI edit as the connection point, again with "localhost:389"